# Is there any way to make the last div not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am wonder if there is any way to make the last div not clickable. I have 10 divs and all of them are clickable. As you can see they are fading in, but I want the last div to fade in and do something if clicked. However I would like to separate the last div and make it do something else.

```
$(".questions").children().hide();
$(" div.questions > div:nth-child("+history[get_number]+")").fadeIn();
```

To make it clear. I have questions and it will add divs every time we answer to the question and going to the next. So this code will proceed to all divs that have been shown. But I want the last div not to proceed.

Comment: How about :last-child?

Comment: Hmm, I have made the codes so it proceed on all divs, but is it any way to do that the codes are proceeding on all divs except the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user6186 answer should work.  An alternative is to put the test in the click event:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.questions > div', function(){
        if( $(this).is(':last-child') ){
            alert('Last Question');
        } else {
            alert('Regular Question');
        }
    });
});
```

However, you might want to consider adding a "last-question" class to the final div server side instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$("div.questions > div:last").unbind('click');
```

If you're using `on()`, then you can do `$("div.questions > div:last").off('click');`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

To add a click listener to all divs except the last one :

```
$(document).on('click', '.questions > div:not(:last-child)', function(){
    alert('Regular Question');
});
```

To add a click listener to only the last div

```
$(document).on('click', '.questions > div:last-child', function(){
    alert('Specific Question');
});
```

Comment: The first code will proceed this alert('Regular Question'); on all divs except the last one?

Comment: yes, that's true, if you want all divs do the same and just add a specific action beside regular action, just remove `:not(:last-child)`

Comment: the last one will proceed something else on the last code?